# _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of type UserForum

Tags: flutter, api, exception

I'm having problems retrieving data from the object user in forums here's the card that im trying to implement

```
class ForumCard extends StatelessWidget {

  final int index;
  final dynamic data ;
  late Forum _forum;
  ForumCard(this.index, this.data ,{Key? key}) : super(key: key){
    _forum = Forum(data['title'], data['description'], baseUrl + data['imageUrl'], data['ForumLikes'].length, data['ForumComments'].length, data['user']);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .95,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .05),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(children: [
            Text(_forum.userForum.firstName),
          ],),
```

And here's the models:

```
class Forum {
  final String _title;
  final String _description;
 final String _imageUrl;
 final int _ForumLikes;
 final int _ForumComments;
 final UserForum _userForum;

  Forum(this._title, this._description, this._imageUrl, this._ForumLikes, this._ForumComments, this._userForum);

  String get imageUrl => _imageUrl;

  String get description => _description;

  String get title => _title;

  int get ForumComments => _ForumComments;

  int get ForumLikes => _ForumLikes;

  UserForum get userForum => _userForum;
}

class UserForum {
 final String _firstName;
 final String _lastName;
 final String _imageUrl;

 UserForum(this._firstName, this._lastName, this._imageUrl);

 String get imageUrl => _imageUrl;

  String get lastName => _lastName;

  String get firstName => _firstName;
}
```

the API call in here

```
  late StreamController _streamController;
  late Stream _stream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamController = StreamController();
    _stream = _streamController.stream;
    getForums();
  }

  getForums() async {
    var response = await ForumsApi().getForums();
    _streamController.add(response);
  }
```

I'm using stream builder and list view and all the data are from a list so i return a list in the getForums() function

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: _stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                var myData = [];
                myData = snapshot.data as List<dynamic>;
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                     Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: myData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, i) => Center(
                            child: ForumCard(
                              i,
                              myData[i],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }),
```

What should i do to get rid of that exception?

Comment: How is the `ForumsApi().getForums();` implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `ForumCard`:

```
  ForumCard(this.index, this.data ,{Key? key}) : super(key: key){
     final userMap = data['user'];
     final userForum = UserForum(userMap["firstName"], userMap["lastName"], userMap["imageUrl"] );
    _forum = Forum(data['title'], data['description'], baseUrl + data['imageUrl'], data['ForumLikes'].length, data['ForumComments'].length, 
userForum);
  }
```